# Altium - broken unconnected nets

Tags: pcb-design, altium, drc

I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with these nets? 
"Design -> Netlist -> Clear all nets" will delete only the functional ones and these unconnected ones remain. 
Can anyone tell me what happened and how to fix this?
Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Route them and then re-run the DRC.

Comment: Which Altium version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As these traces are not assigned to any net, they are not deleted by "Design -> Netlist -> Clear all nets".
There are two possibilities to do so:

1. Use "Route » Un-Route » All", which clears all physical connections on your PCB (https://www.altium.com/documentation/17.0/display/ADES/PCB_Cmd-UnRoute((UnRoute))_AD)
2. Right click a trace -> find similar objects and select the layer and switch to "Same". This selects all tracks on the specified layer and you can easily delete them

Answer (score 1):

Go to the board then click on Tools >> **Reset Error Markers** will solve you problem.

[image: Remove altium DRC error markers]

Answer (score 0):

Unroute has no effect.  These are considered errors.  From the Tools -> Menu -> **Reset Error Markers** will remove all these ones